# VIEW Duplicate column name 'ISLAND'

Tags: sql, view

```
CREATE VIEW ALL_TABLES AS SELECT * FROM employee_view, av_pay;
```

I keep getting error message how do I overcome this

> VIEW  Duplicate column name 'ISLAND'

av_pay:

[image]

employee_view:

[image]

Comment: I seriously doubt that you want a Cartesian product between the two tables.

Comment: `CREATE VIEW ALL_TABLES (c1, c2, c3 ...) AS SELECT ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a **select ***, which will output the same column names as defined in the tables you are querying. As you have both columns defined with the same name in both, there you have the error.

So either rename one of the columns or change the query to something like:

```
select employee_view.ISLAND ISLAND_V, av_pay.ISLAND ISLAND_P, ... FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The db engine complaints because your select clause is "*" and both the source tables contain the column "island". As a result, the dbms does not know which column should be returned - from employee_view or av_pay?

BTW, a select from 2 tables without a join will result in a cartesian product...